# Get YouTube playlist videos anonymously

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to display a list of videos from a YouTube playlist in an intranet application.

Is it possible to get the list of videos from a YouTube playlist using the Data api (or any other way) without requiring the user to login?

Everything that I have read so far in the YouTube data api requires the user to be signed in to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately, you can't access youtube data API with anonymously user.

Your application must have authorization credentials to be able to use the YouTube Data API.
The Developers Console associates your credentials with the APIs that you indicate that your application will use. Note that the Developers Console does not allow you to select the YouTube Data API (v2). However, authorization credentials for the v3 API will also work for the v2 API.
If possible, you should actually use YouTube Data API (v3) rather than the v2 API in your application. The YouTube API blog explains some of the benefits that the newer API offers, and we have added a year's worth of additional functionality to the API since that blog post!

related link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Client_Side_Web_Applications_Flow

Comment: Do you have to use the OAuth authentication, involving the user, or can you do it by just using the API key?